# Decision tree overfitting even with training/validation/testing data

Tags: validation, testing

My problem is as follows. I have 6 dataset (collected from different days) that I want to build a decision tree classifier for. I need to find the optimal tree depth parameter to avoid over fitting and have good prediction for new data.

My first attempt was to split each dataset by 50%/25%/25% into training/validation/testing, and merged them into three big files. I produced a graph of accuracy vs tree depth, trained using the big training set and calculated the accuracy from the big validation set. However, I noticed the accuracy of the validation set kept increasing as the tree depth increased and never went down!

The accuracy reached around 99%, at a tree depth of 20. Even the test set's accuracy was around 99%. I assumed it had to be over fitting, based on my knowledge of the data. I confirmed this by removing one of the dataset, leaving only 5. I trained on the remaining 5 dataset using the same procedure as above, splitting into training/validation/testing and training it at a depth of 20. This time I tested it against the dataset I left out and it produced a very poor result, accuracy in the low 50%.

It turns out my dataset has a lot of 'repetitive' data due to the time-series nature of it. To the point that sampling 25-50% any of the dataset is probably equivalent to sampling 100%, hence the over fitting. I decided to try a different strategy by randomly shuffling the 6 dataset and splitting them into training/validation via 3/3, repeat it 20 times and average the results to find the optimal tree depth. I'm still waiting for the result, should be done in a few days ...

So my question (finally!) is whether what I did is a sound method? What other kind of *funny* data should I be aware of? It seems like my dataset has a 'gotcha' that I have seen mentioned anywhere.

Comment: It's better to set a minimum number of samples per leaf instead of a max tree height.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was quite subtle. Long story short, **DON'T up sample your data (for unbalanced dataset) and do cross-validation!**

Long story. I had an unbalanced dataset where I had more negative samples than positive by about 7-10 times. My choice was either to up sample the positive via duplication or down sample the negative. I went with up sampling,. This means during cross validation, each fold has a very high chance of picking all of the original positive samples and thus overfit the positive samples. I'm now down sampling the negative samples, doing the cross validation a few times and shuffling the data. Seems to work now.